# Assigning Value to New Variable Based on Specific Values in Another Variable in R

Tags: r, variable-assignment

I have a data.frame that contains state names and I would like to create a new variable called "region" in which a value is assigned based on the state that is found under the "state" variable.

For example, if the state variable has "Alabama" or "Georgia", I would like to have "Region" assigned as "South". If state is "Washington" or "California", I would like it assigned to "West". I have to do this for each of the 48 contiguous U.S. states, and I'm having difficulty figuring out the best way to do this. Any help in this (I'm sure simple) procedure would be great. What I am looking for is something like this in the end:

```
State      Region
Wyoming    West
Michigan   Midwest
Alabama    South
Georgia    South
California West
Texas      Central
```

And to be clear, I don't have the regions in a separate file, i have to create this as a new variable and create the region names myself. I'm just looking for a way that the code can go through all 3000 lines that I have and can automatically assign the region name once I tell it how to do so.

Comment: A common approach for this is to make a lookup table that has all the states in one column and their respective region in another. Then you can join that to the original data using base `merge` or other alternatives like `dplyr::left_join`. It is possible to construct a massive `ifelse` statement but that would be very unwieldy here; and dplyr::case_when wouldn't be much better.

Comment: It will be easier for people to give you specific answers if you can provide reproducible data (in the form of code that can be run) for them to load and test potential approaches with. this is often easiest using the `dput` command to make a code "recipe" that recreates a data object. for instance, `dput(head(FIRST_TABLE))` would produce code that exactly recreates the first few (6) rows of `FIRST_TABLE`.

Comment: I'm very illiterate when it comes to imputing code on this site since I'm still a beginner overall. I've tried typing in a table sample of what I would like it to look like. I'm not really sure what a lookup table is.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than type the region for every state, you can use the built-in "state.name" and "state.region" variables from the 'datasets' package (like Jon Spring suggests in his comment), e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(datasets)

state_lookup_table <- data.frame(name = state.name,
                                 region = state.region)

my_df <- data.frame(place = c("Washington", "California"),
                    value = c(1000, 2000))
my_df
#>        place value
#> 1 Washington  1000
#> 2 California  2000

my_df %>%
  left_join(state_lookup_table, by = c("place" = "name"))
#>        place value region
#> 1 Washington  1000   West
#> 2 California  2000   West
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I would go this way:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("john", "will", "thomas", "Ali"),
                 state = c("California", "Alabama", "Washington", "Georgia"))

region_df <- data.frame(state= c("Alabama", "Georgia", "Washington"),
                        region = c("south", "south", "west"))

merged.df <- merge(df, region_df, all.x = TRUE, on= "state")
```

Comment: I don't actually have the region names in a separate vector that I can specify. I have over 3000 lines of data and need the program to assign them based on the state name. So something like "if state is Alabama Georgia etc, then region is South" and so on for the other regions. I jsut don't know how to do this.

Comment: yes that's exactly what it does. you have your 3000 lines of data in df, and you have your mapping state to region in region_df, and your "if/then/else" is the merge..

Comment: I don't have the region_df though. THat's the issue. I need code that tells R to assign a region name to a state without having an actual vector. This doesn't do what I need. The only information I currently have in my data frame is the state name, I have no region names at all.

Comment: I understand. But you said “ i have to create this as a new variable and create the region names myself”. The new variable is region_df. It does what you said you want. In any case please have a look at jared_mamrot’s answer which use predefined vectors holding the region information. I would use them.

Comment: Yes. That’s the problem. I don’t have a pre-defined vector of regions that I can join to the data, so this doesn’t help. That includes jared_mamrot’s answer which requires that I have a predefined vector. I basically need to create an empty variable column and use some sort of if else statement to assign values. I can’t use any of the methods here because they all rely on a pre-defined vector.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a reference to do so. For your specific question, a dict would be the best solution.

```
ref_ge <- {}
ref_ge["Georgia"]="South"
ref_ge["Alabama"]="South"
ref_ge["California"]="West"
ref1["Georgia"]

#Or, if you could read the state->region information from an excel to a dataframe
df=data.frame(state=c("Georgia","Alabama","California"),region=c("South","South","West"))
ref2 <- df$region
names(ref2) <- df$state
ref2["Georgia"]
```